# Retrieve SQL Protocol Status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, wmi, wmi-query

Using SQL query or WMI, I want to retrieve whether SQL protocol such as Named Pipes, TCP/IP is enabled or not.

I need to do this for SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [WMI Provider for Configuration Management Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186452.aspx) include the [`ServerNetworkProtocol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179574.aspx) WMI class, which list the protocols installed on an instance of Microsoft SQL Server, this class is located in the `root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10` namespace (for sql server 2008, in other versions you must modify the namespace).

Check this C# sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                ManagementScope Scope;                

                if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                {
                    ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
                    Conn.Username  = "";
                    Conn.Password  = "";
                    Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ComputerManagement10", ComputerName), Conn);
                }
                else
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ComputerManagement10", ComputerName), null);

                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM ServerNetworkProtocol");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","ProtocolDisplayName",WmiObject["ProtocolDisplayName"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Enabled",WmiObject["Enabled"]);// Boolean
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","InstanceName",WmiObject["InstanceName"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","MultiIpConfigurationSupport",WmiObject["MultiIpConfigurationSupport"]);// Boolean
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","ProtocolName",WmiObject["ProtocolName"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine();


                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

This will return something like this

```
ProtocolDisplayName                 Shared Memory
Enabled                             True
InstanceName                        MSSQLSERVER
MultiIpConfigurationSupport         False
ProtocolName                        Sm

ProtocolDisplayName                 Named Pipes
Enabled                             False
InstanceName                        MSSQLSERVER
MultiIpConfigurationSupport         False
ProtocolName                        Np

ProtocolDisplayName                 TCP/IP
Enabled                             True
InstanceName                        MSSQLSERVER
MultiIpConfigurationSupport         True
ProtocolName                        Tcp

ProtocolDisplayName                 VIA
Enabled                             False
InstanceName                        MSSQLSERVER
MultiIpConfigurationSupport         False
ProtocolName                        Via
```

Comment: Thanx for the Help ,                                                But Above code Throw Error in my Windows Server 2008 64 bit.

Comment: @John, this error is caused because you are using a invalid namespace, for SQL Server 2005 use `ComputerManagement`, for SQL Server2008 `ComputerManagement10` and for SQL Server 2012 `ComputerManagement11`